# ElasticSearch Spark Error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am new to ElasticSearch and I am trying to write some Apache Spark code to save some data into ElasticSearch.  I have entered the following lines into SparkShell:

```
 import org.elasticsearch.spark._
 val myMap = Map("France" -> "FRA", "United States" -> "US")
 val myRDD = sc.makeRDD(Seq(myMap))
 myRDD.saveToEs("Country/Abbrv")
```

The error:

```
 org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIlegalArgumentException:  Cannot determine write shards for [Country/Abbrv]; likely its format is incorrect (maybe it contains illegal characters?)
```

Spark 2.0.0
ElasticSearch-Spark 2.3.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not set the --conf var before launching spark shell.  It needs to look like the following:

```
 spark-shell --jars {path}/elasticsearch-spark_2.11-2.3.4.jar --conf spark.es.resource=Country/Abbrv
```

Answer (score -1):

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine write shards for [custAct_index/custAct_index_type]; likely its format is incorrect (maybe it contains illegal characters?)
```

Due to the naming convention, it is producing this error.
change the capitalized char to lower case will solve the issue.

```
custAct_index/custAct_index_type ---> cust_act_index/cust_act_index_type
```

this fix worked for me...