# Connect Spark 2.X to ElasticSearch 2.X

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm working with Spark and ElasticSearch and can't find how to use Spark 2.X with ElasticSearch 2.x.
ElasticSearch Spark libs support only Spark 1.6 for ES 2.X
and supports Spark 2 for ES 5.alpha
What do you use to connect Spark to ElasticSearch?

Comment: are you getting an error of a sort ?

Comment: Yes, elasticsearch hadoop and spark elasticsearch streaming only support Spark 1.6. Spark 2 supports only ElasticSearch 5 alpha

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying here,  you mean to say there is no support for latest version of ES (which is alpha currently) ? Can't we get back to bit older and bit stable version to integrate with Spark ?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this.

#### [Apache Spark support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-native)

Apache Spark is computing framework that is not tied to Map/Reduce itself however it does integrate with Hadoop, mainly to HDFS. elasticsearch-hadoop allows Elasticsearch to be used in Spark in two ways: through the dedicated support available since 2.1 or through the Map/Reduce bridge since 2.0. Spark 2.0 is supported in elasticsearch-hadoop since version 5.0

Hope that helps!

Also have a loot at [ElasticSearch Spark Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773706/elasticsearch-spark-error)
Where user is using spark 2.0 with lower version(Spark 2.0.0 ElasticSearch-Spark 2.3.4) of Elastic search and @Crackerman was able to resolve his issue(other issue not version related stuff)

Comment: was my answer helpful ? can you able to check?

Answer (score 0):

i am using spark 2.2 read elasticsearch 5.5.2 is work

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.10"
val spark = "2.2.0"
val es = "5.5.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % es,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % spark % "provided" ,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % spark % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % spark % "provided"
)
 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .config("es.nodes",locahost)
    .config("es.port","9200")
    .appName("ES")
    .master("local[*]")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

   sparkSession.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.query", "?q=id:(123)") 
  .load("es_index/es_type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it supports it.

You can find `org.elasticsearch` libraries here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20

Also, take care to match the same scala version (2.11 or 2.10). For instance, Ambari provides Spark2 - scala 2.11.